# Get environment variable from python script

Tags: bash, scripting, python, environment-variables

I have bash script `config.sh` in which several variables are exported , and I need those variable in my python script.

**config.sh**

```bsh
export VAR="YES"
```

My approach is to source the `config.sh` from the python script and the use `os` to get them:

```py
import os

if os.system("source ./config.sh") != 0:
    print("Failed to execute the script")
else:
    x = os.getenv('VAR')
```

Somehow the value for x is `None` because it's not finding the env var. Any advice ? Thx

Python version 2.7.5

Comment: They must be in the environment **before** python launches.

Comment: Did you try something like `sh config.sh && python script.py`?

Comment: Or `VAR="YES" python my.py`?

Comment: Just to explain, your python script is a running process. It invokes a system call, which is another process. In that (child) process the config.sh file is sourced, which sets the value of VAR to YES. Then that process (the child) ends. Nothing has changed in the parent's (python) environment, so when the python script goes and gets the value of the environment variable VAR, it's probably not set. Or it could be set to “NO”. Children inherit their parent's exported variables, but parents don't get their child's exported variables.

Comment: Thx for the explanation @Larry , also I checked the documentation and `os.system.__doc__ ` 'Execute the command in a subshell.'

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_output()` or `commands.getstatusoutput()`. They returns error code and stdout. However, support for `commands.getstatusoutput()` ends in new versions of Python. It is better to use `subprocess.check_output()` instead. You should also add what version of Python you want this solution to, because there are differences. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Yes there are differences between `os.environ.get()` vs `os.getenv()`. The `os.getenv()` does not raise an exception, but returns `None` on errors - please check also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924471/difference-between-os-getenv-and-os-environ-get